# How to change language from finnish to english in windows 7 home premium

Tags: windows-7, windows, 32-bit

I bought the windows 7 home premium edition here in finland and i have installed in finnish hoping that i can change the language later to english. Iam surprised to see that i dont have option to change the language. I didnt see 'Display Language' in Region and Language'. Can any one know how to to change the language to english. Please help

Answer (score 2):

Bad news: the ability to change languages by installing language packs in Windows 7 is not available in the Home Premium edition.  From the [relevant article on Windows 7 Center](http://windows7center.com/tutorials/how-to-download-and-install-windows-7-beta-language-packs-mui-packs/): "This feature is only available in Windows 7 Enterprise and Ultimate."

Answer (score 1):

You could do an Anytime Upgrade to Windows 7 Ultimate and then change the language to English. Not sure if Anytime Upgrade is available in Finland.

You could also try borrowing Windows 7 Home Premium English media and using your product key.